# How do I fix a circular reference issue?

Tags: excel

I am getting the awesome "There are more than one or more circular references where a formula refers to its own cell..." warning on Excel.

I've tried to delete what shows up in the Error Checking option but they still show and it seems like there might be a bunch or them.

I know there is a formula to help me fix it, but I don't quite understand it. Could someone please help me with my issue?

Values are from cells A1 to AFT155.

Thank you

Comment: What's the formula, and in what cell? What's it telling you is the circular reference?

Comment: any screenshots?